# Рисование на Canvas фигуры с градиентом

Tags: android, android-canvas

Как нарисовать круг с заливкой градиентом и контуром который тоже с градиентом.
У меня есть обычный  Paint с заливкой:

```
mProgressPaint.setStyle(Style.FILL);
mProgressPaint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#09A513"));
```

В cети нашел что  можно градиент сделать тако, но он все равно получаеться одного цвета. И это не делает контур.

```
mProgresGoldPain.setStyle(Style.FILL);
mProgresGoldPain.setShader(new LinearGradient(0, 0, getWidth(), 0, color, color2, Shader.TileMode.MIRROR));
```

Потом рисую так:

```
canvas.drawCircle(dX, dY, mRadius, mProgressPaint);
```

Вобщем вот пример того что я пытаюсь сделать:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно сделать контур отдельно:

```
mProgressPaint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
```

А затем можно задать им отдельно градиент [как описано здесь](https://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/393-urok-165-risovanie-bitmapshader-lineargradient-radialgradient-sweepgradient.html).

Для класса `RadialGradient` указываем центр и радиус, и тогда градиент пойдет от центра к краям. А `SweepGradient` – градиент, который идет по кругу вокруг центра. У этих двух классов, аналогично `LinearGradient`, есть простой конструктор, где можно указать два цвета, а есть посложнее - с возможностью указания массива цветов и их соотношений.

Подробнее по [ссылке](https://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/377-urok-162-grafika-drawable-shape-gradient.html).

И документация [RadialGradient](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/RadialGradient), [SweepGradient](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/SweepGradient).